# Django ModelForms: cleanest way to hide fields and enforce defaults

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-forms

Let's say I have a single ModelForm which can be filled out by different tiers of users. The Admin can edit any field of that form; but for other users, I need to have certain fields pre-defined, and read-only and/or hidden.

Using my CBV's `get_form_kwargs` method, I have made the form aware of the user that's bringing it up, and, in its `__init__` method I react accordingly, tweaking the form's `exclude`, and the fields' `required` and `initial` properties; and then, in my view's `form_valid`, I further enforce the values. But, frankly, I'm neither sure that every operation I do is actually needed, nor whether there's some gaping hole I'm not aware of.

So, what's the best, cleanest way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there aren't a lot of combinations, I would create a different form that meets the different needs of your users. Then override `def get_form_class` and return the correct form based on your needs. This keeps the different use cases separate and gives flexibility if you need to change things in the future without breaking the other forms.

```
# models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = model.CharField(max_length=100)
    baz = model.CharField(max_length=100)
    biz = model.CharField(max_length=100)

# forms.py
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):  # for admins
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):  # users who can't see bar
    boo = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        exclude = ['bar']

class FooFormN(forms.ModelForm):  # as many different scenarios as you need
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super(FooFormN, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['biz'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Foo

# views.py
class SomeView(UpdateView):
    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name="some_group").exists():
            return FooForm
        # etc.
```

Comment: This is one possibility. I had considered this, but I had not realized that it actually *does* make sense.