# Django dynamic form & ordering of fields

Tags: django, forms

I have a form for logging a 'ticket' to a department.

It is a dynamic form which has additional custom fields depending on the form category/department.

Each ticket has standard fields such as title, date, content. Some have fields called custom_acbdef which allows department to ask additional questions on their forms.

These additional fields always appear at the bottom of the form which is OK at the moment. (I add the model form then just loop trough additional fields and add them to self.fields)

Now, I want to add an additional standard field called 'PDF attachment' but I want this to always appear at the bottom of the form. The problem at the moment is all standard fields appear at the top and custom fields appear at the bottom.

```
class Meta:
    model = Ticket
    fields = ('ticket_category','ticket_branch','ticket_content', 'ticket_attachment1')
```

So in the above, I'd want all to insert all my custom fields inbetween ticket_content and ticket_attachment. Any ideas how I can do this? All the custom form fields have dynamic field names but always start with 'custom_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When things start to become unmanageable inside my forms `__init__`, I generally take one of the following approaches:

### Create a Factory

Leveraging closures, write a function to build out the `fields` dynamically then return that class.

```
def TicketForm():
    fields = ['title', 'date', 'content']

    for custom_field in custom_fields:
        fields.append(custom_field)

    fields.append('ticket_content')
    fields.append('ticket_attachment1')

    class _TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Ticket
            fields = fields

    return _TicketForm
```

### Multiple forms

I'll create several different forms based on the use case, then within my view determine which one should be returned. [I posted an example of this yesterday.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381925/django-modelforms-cleanest-way-to-hide-fields-and-enforce-defaults/17382654#17382654)

For further reading, [check out a post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) by James Bennett (django core dev) regarding dynamic forms.

Comment: I actually got it working by deleting the field then re-adding it again after the custom fields loop but your solutions looks better to me. Great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but recently has been published a
package that fulfills this purpose.

It allows to define new fields on-the-fly and populate them in forms and database in a very simple way.

Here is the link

[dinadata by undersat package](https://github.com/undersat/DinaData)